# How to disable all button/image/div except currently selected in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am beginner to angularjs. But i know jQuery.
I have 3 images/buttons/div, currently i am working on 1 div, i need to disable remaing div/image/button. exact like the below image.

[image]

How can i do this onclick event in angularjs, please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share you code? so we can help you out easly

Answer (score 0):

for disabling a button , you can add attribute data-ng-disabled to the button.

```
<div>
    <button id = "button1" data-ng-disabled = "disable1">A</button>
    <button id = "button2" data-ng-disabled = "disable2">B</button>
    <button id = "button3" data-ng-disabled = "disable3">C</button>
</div>
```

then , in the controller, you can have

```
$scope.disable1 = false;
$scope.disable2 = true;
$scope.disable3 = true;
```